# Authorization is required to perform that action after several hours later

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a simple Google Apps Script bound to a Google Sheet. It works successfully when run manually, and works for the first few hours when run with a time trigger.

However, several hours later the time trigger will stop working to due loss of permissions, apparently. The "Summary of Failures" email from apps-scripts-notifications@google.com says:

```
"Authorization is required to perform that action."
```

Anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
function Autocopy() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Weekly 
Record");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var range1 = sheet.getRange(1,3);
  var date1 = range1.getValue();
  var newdata = new Date();
  rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(4, 3, 69, 36);
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(4,9));
  rangeToClean = sheet.getRange(4, 3, 69, 6);
  rangeToClean.clearContent();  
  range1.setValue(newdata);
 }[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: "Summary of failures" always mentions line number where error happened, do you have it?

Comment: The error message is "Authorization is required to perform that action".

Answer (score 0):

This is a know Google Apps Script issue that happens when you are logged into multiple Google accounts in the same browser.

To confirm, open Google Chrome, go to the menu and choose New Incognito Window. Here open the same Google sheet and run the script again.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to use Chrome Incognito model to granted permission to run it and set the script time trigger again, but one hour later, it got revoked again.